# Как экранировать строку для защиты от SQL-injection?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Мне оставили такой комментарий:

`Лучше table экранировать от потенциальной sql инъекции`

Вот к такой строке:

`String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE phone = :phone", table)`

`phone` я подставляю через map в PreparedStatement, а как быть с именем таблицы?

Как мне экранировать `table`, чтобы учесть этот момент?

Comment: Я должен в кавычки обернуть имя таблицы? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Кавычки не помогут (пример `X"; delete from "X` - удалит из Х). Откуда может взяться table? Пользователь вводит в текстовом виде?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA table в application.property передается, если потребуется таблица может быть переименована или использоваться другая в качестве источника. Этим будет заниматься сопровождение, если понадобится. Они просто залезут в application.properties и поменяют имя таблицы, как настройку сервиса.

Comment: Нужно определиться от какого риска защищаетесь. Так как сопровождение может менять настройки, то тем более они могут их читать. А значит могут взять параметри доступа к БД и вручную сделать любый запросы, которые имеет право делать пользовать БД, которого использует приложение. Так что от злого умысла тут не защититься

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Понятно. А если в общем, существует способ подставлять имя таблицы как переменную? или ни каких способов защиты нет?

Comment: Только как строку. Можно использовать список разрешенных, как уже написали, или проверить конфигурацию при старте, чтоб там было имя существующей таблицы. Проверять по метаданным, а не путем запроса к таблице, см. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-

Comment: Если потребовалось задавать имя таблицы динамически, то есть серьёзные проблемы в архитектуре. И, если не поздно, надо от них избавляться. *А если в общем, существует способ подставлять имя таблицы как переменную? или ни каких способов защиты нет?* В рамках одного запроса - невозможно. А вот в формате хранимой процедуры - возможно. Например, передаём в ХП имя как обычный параметр, там проверяем переданное значение на отсутствие невалидных символов и формируем VIEW ALGORITHM = MERGE с предопределённым именем, которое просто маппит таблицу. После чего работаем с представлением, но зная имя.

Answer (score 0):

Подготовленные переменные применяются исключительно для значений колонок, а не для имён таблиц. Если хотите, чтобы пользователь подставлял имя, то вам надо завести массив имён таблиц (белый список), которые можно писать. Далее сравнивать написанное пользователем имя таблицы с содержанием белого списка. Если его там нет, делать атата пользователю